# Rails 4 reject_if in nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I have a model `Profile` which accepts `ProfileLanguage` as nested attributes:

```ruby
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :profile_languages, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile_languages, reject_if: proc { |a| a[:language_name].blank? }
end

class ProfileLanguage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :profile
    validates_inclusion_of :proficiency, :in => %w( 1 2 3 4 5 ), :message => "Veuillez choisir un niveau valide"
end
```

And here is the form I'm using:

```
<%= f.fields_for :profile_languages do |pl| %>
        <div class="plform-group">
            <div class="form-planguage-half">
              <%= pl.text_field :language_name, class: 'form-control form-two-half'  %>
            </div>
            <div class="form-planguage-half-last">
              <%= pl.select(:proficiency, [
                      ["Débutant", 1], 
                      ["Intermédiaire", 2], 
                      ["Courant", 3], 
                      ["Bilingue", 4], 
                      ["Natif", 5]], 
                      {}, {class: "form-control form-two-half"}) %>
            </div>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

the problem is when the field of `language_name` is blank it will not be rejected because of the `proficiency` select so how can resolve this problem

Comment: Take a look at the option: `include_blank` for [`select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) helper.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add `validates :language_name, presence: true` to your `ProfileLanguage` model. This would make sure that no record of `ProfileLanguage` will be persisted without a `:language_name`.